# un-comment a specific line in a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a file which contains the line below.

```
#LoadModule status_module "${PRODUCT_HOME}/modules/mod_status.so"
```

I want one `sed` to un-comment the line from above and one command to comment it. I tried the command below.

```
sed "/^#/LoadModule status_module "${PRODUCT_HOME}/modules/mod_status.so"/LoadModule status_module "${PRODUCT_HOME}/modules/mod_status.so"/g" file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is, that things like `"` and `${PRODUCT_HOME}` are interpreted by the shell. You have to escape them properly so that they reach `sed` as literals. Also `/` is is treated specially by `sed` (in the way you use it) and has to be escaped too.

We will use a variable for escaping and making things easier to read:

```
line='LoadModule status_module "${PRODUCT_HOME}/modules/mod_status.so"'
```

Now to the `sed` command. If you want to replace something, the syntax is `s/search/replace/`. The string `search` will be replaced by `replace`. Instead of `s/search/replace/` we can also write `s:search:replace:`, allowing us to use the `/` inside the `search` and `replace` text.

**uncomment**

```
 sed "s:#$line:$line:"
```

**comment**

```
sed "s:$line:#$line:"
```